# How to examine length of vector lines in qgis/grass?

Tags: length

I have vector layer of lines. How can I examine length of lines?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In QGIS start an edit session for your line layer, then open the attribute table.  Click the Field Calculator button, create a new field with a "Double" data type, set the width and precision, then enter $length in the Expression area.  When you click OK the length for each feature will be calculated.  The length will be expressed in units of the layer's coordinate system, so you'll get meters if it is in meters, but you'll get degrees if your CRS is in degrees.